# Get the list files of certain pattern

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I have the following files:

```
TAMF_Flight1.txt
TAMF_Flight1_profile.txt
TAMF_Flight2.txt
TAMF_Flight2_profile.txt
...
TAMF_Flight10.txt
TAMF_Flight10_profile.txt
TAMF_Flight11.txt
TAMF_Flight11_profile.txt
```

What should I put in the pattern to get only:

```
TAMF_Flight1.txt
TAMF_Flight2.txt
...
TAMF_Flight10.txt
TAMF_Flight11.txt
```

or only:

```
TAMF_Flight1_profile.txt
TAMF_Flight2_profile.txt
...
TAMF_Flight10_profile.txt
TAMF_Flight11_profile.txt
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, it's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. It's generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it.

Comment: what regexes did you try already? by showing those, folks may be able to provide more in-depth guidance to help you fish vs fish for you.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to use list.files(pattern = paste0("TAMF_Flight",1:2,".txt")), but the output produced is only TAMF_Flight1.txt

Comment: `list.files` requires path to your file names

Comment: Hi, I have already set a default file path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myfiles <- c('TAMF_Flight1.txt',
             'TAMF_Flight1_profile.txt',
             'TAMF_Flight2.txt',
             'TAMF_Flight2_profile.txt')

grep( "TAMF_Flight[0-9]+[^_]", myfiles, value = TRUE)
# [1] "TAMF_Flight1.txt" "TAMF_Flight2.txt"

grep( "TAMF_Flight[0-9]+[_]", myfiles, value = TRUE)
# [1] "TAMF_Flight1_profile.txt" "TAMF_Flight2_profile.txt"
```

using pattern inside `list.files()`

```
list.files( path = ".", pattern = "TAMF_Flight[0-9]+\\.txt")
list.files( path = ".", pattern = "TAMF_Flight[0-9]+[_]")
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried it in my code, but it doesn't work with flight 10 and above

Comment: Hi, the second list.files is able to obtain only _profile files. However, for the first one, it works only for flight1 to flight9. For flight10 and flight11, it takes both _profile and the one without _profile

Comment: you can add .txt in the first one

Comment: I am adding an escape character for . like \\. in the first one